# Why aren't anchor links working on android in landscape mode?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, event-handling, anchor

I have a website deployed here: https://polina-gushchyna.netlify.app/

The website works as expected on iOS and Android, but I'm encountering a problem in landscape mode on Android where the anchor links don't work. I'm having trouble pinpointing the cause, and I suspect it may be related to event handlers.

I attempted to resolve the conflict between anchor links and event handlers by modifying the handleClick function as follows:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (e.target.nodeName === "NAV") return;

    if (e.target.tagName === 'A' && e.target.getAttribute('href').startsWith('#')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Other event handling code...

    if (e.target.tagName === 'A' && e.target.getAttribute('href').startsWith('#')) {
        const targetId = e.target.getAttribute('href').substring(1);
        const targetElement = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (targetElement) {
            targetElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        }
    }
}
```

Despite these modifications, the anchor links still don't work in landscape mode on Android. Can you provide any insights into why this issue might be occurring and how I can resolve it? Thank you for your help.